# How to make a custom confirmation dialog for critical actions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a dialog to confirm action by user.

We can achieve that by `confirm()` dialog like this:

```js
function btnChangeBodyColorFunc() {
  let text = "You are going to change body color.Are you sure";
  if (confirm(text) == true) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("You changed!");
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";
    console.log("You canceled!");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btnChangeBodyColorFunc()">Change body color to red</button>
```

But can it be sort of custom like this:

```js
let iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
let confirmDialog = document.querySelector(".confirmDialog");

function btnChangeBodyColorFunc() {
  confirmDialog.style.display = "flex";
  if (iConfirmToGoAhead === "true") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("You changed!");
    iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
  } else if (iConfirmToGoAhead === "false") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";
    console.log("You canceled!");
    iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
  }
}

let confirmDialogBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmDialogContent button");
for (let i = 0; i < confirmDialogBtn.length; i++) {
  confirmDialogBtn[i].addEventListener('click', confirmDialogBtnFunc)
}

function confirmDialogBtnFunc() {
  confirmDialog.style.display = "none";
  iConfirmToGoAhead = this.dataset.confirmationValue;
}
```

```css
.confirmDialog {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.confirmDialogContent {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btnChangeBodyColorFunc()">Change body color to red</button>
<div class="confirmDialog">
  <div class="confirmDialogContent">
    You are going to change body color.Are you sure
    <button data-confirmation-value="true">Yes sure</button>
    <button data-confirmation-value="false">No don't change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this way it don't wait for `iConfirmToGoAhead` value to be confirmed and execute the function.
Know this is how JS works that execute the codes which comes first. I tried use of `async` and `await` but that also don't work and throw error(might not applied it right).

Can do required functionality by adding conditions to second function but thought a common way for all critical actions through 1 dialog and change according to it.
Is it possible to have a custom confirmation dialog like this or have to use conditions in 2nd function. Any ideas are most welcome

**Thanks for help in advance**

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in this line, any button click action inside the class `confirmDialogContent`, should trigger an event & call this function `confirmDialogBtnFunc`. But you have written all functionality inside the function `btnChangeBodyColorFunc`.

This function will call only when you click the button `Change body color to red`. If you make any click event inside the confirmation popup, it will call the `confirmDialogBtnFunc` function as you mentioned inside the for loop

```
let confirmDialogBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmDialogContent button");
  for (let i = 0; i < confirmDialogBtn.length; i++) {
    confirmDialogBtn[i].addEventListener('click', confirmDialogBtnFunc)
  }
```

I have rewritten the code, Please look into it.
I hope that would be useful for you :)

```js
let iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
let confirmDialog = document.querySelector(".confirmDialog");

function btnChangeBodyColorFunc() {
  confirmDialog.style.display = "flex";
}

let confirmDialogBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmDialogContent button");
for (let i = 0; i < confirmDialogBtn.length; i++) {
  confirmDialogBtn[i].addEventListener('click', confirmDialogBtnFunc)
}

function confirmDialogBtnFunc() {

  iConfirmToGoAhead = this.dataset.confirmationValue;
  confirmDialog.style.display = "flex";
  if (iConfirmToGoAhead === "true") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("You changed!");
    iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
  } else if (iConfirmToGoAhead === "false") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";
    console.log("You canceled!");
    iConfirmToGoAhead = ""
  }
  confirmDialog.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.confirmDialog {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.confirmDialogContent {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="btnChangeBodyColorFunc()">Change body color to red</button>
  <div class="confirmDialog">
    <div class="confirmDialogContent">
      You are going to change body color.Are you sure
      <button data-confirmation-value="true">Yes sure</button>
      <button data-confirmation-value="false">No don't change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and effort @Plututs +1. I really appreciate your help. And looking for a way that dialog is appeared for all critical actions and just confirm for the action(i.e, yes or no is only checked from dialog while all actions are done to respective functions)

Comment: Instead of running separate dialog function for every critical action. This is my last weapon that you have provided to sort the problem. If possible